# PHPMailer works on localhost, but fails on server

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

My script runs perfect on my localhost on WAMP, but when I try to run it on my server it fails, I tried also to run it on another server and it sends me the same error.
This is the error I get when running the script on the server:

```
> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
> SMTP connect() failed.
```

This is my PHPMailer configuration:

```
                require ('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

                $alertvalue = $_GET["alert"];

                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                echo "<p> Instance created. </p>";
                $mail -> isSMTP();
                $mail -> Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // I've also tried withou the ssl://
                $mail -> Port = 465; // I've also tried 587 and 25
                $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail -> Username = '-------------@gmail.com';
                $mail -> Password = '-------------';
                $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // I've also tried with ssl
                $mail -> SMTPDebug = 1;

                $mail -> From = '--------------@gmail.com';
                $mail -> FromName = '----------';
                $mail -> addAddress('--------------@gmail.com', '----');
```

Any idea why this is happenning? I've looked at several posts with a similar situation but I haven't been able to figure out my problem yet.

Comment: are you using wamp as a server?

Comment: For my localhost, yes, and it works just fine there. But on the server my domain is hosted is where I get that error.

Comment: then theres your problem donot use wamp because i too used it and i was in the same position as you are in noe instead use xampp.IF IT WORKS ON XAMPP IT WILL WORK ON ANY WEB HOST'S SERVERS

Comment: Is it possible it could be as simple as capitalization of the `IsSMTP` and the `AddAddress` methods?

Comment: I will download Xampp and try it there, but why should it make a difference? I corrected the capitalization and still doesn't work. Thank you all for your answers

Comment: I already installer Xampp and my script run just fine there, but it keeps failing on my other server.

Answer (score 3):

Just comment $mail->IsSMTP(); ..I had same problem..On localhost its working and live server not working..After I commented $mail->IsSMTP(); this, Its working fine..Hopes so might be helpful for u it is

Comment: If you disable $mail->IsSMTP() you won't be using the SMTP server which you defined in your configuration. I don't think that's what you want.