# phpmailer works on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-ec2, server

I have form submition with ajax and phpmailer.

On localhost all works great. I recieve the response (the echo from the php file) and get the mail.

On live, I dont get the mail and as a response I get the whole php file.

I use **amazon server.**

My thoughts are that this is something with the server but I dont know where to start from.

here is the ajax function

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'mail/contact_me.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'text',
            data: {data: JSON.stringify(getData())},
            success:function(response){
                $('#success').text(response);
            }

        });
```

and the phpfile

```
 <?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com','name');
$mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('someemail@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'My Subject';
$mail->Body = $message;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    echo ' Thank you for contact us';
}
```

}

Comment: Exactly same, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942933/phpmailer-works-on-localhost-but-fails-on-server#answer-34939423)

Comment: Does the server support PHP mail() function?

Comment: You get the source of the php file? Can the server you are using run php files?

Comment: Check if PHP-fpm is working on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the php is not working correctly. Have you configured the web server correctly? make sure php was installed and enabled in your web server. If you are using Apache, check the `mod_php` installed. In Nginx, check `php5-fpm`

Comment: I will check it. Thanks!